# Is it possible to remove DLL dependency due to interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, reference

Let's say my library class (in assembly A) have a method `GetFoo()` returns a type `Foo`. `Foo` implements several interfaces, including `IBar` in assembly B. When a client code calls `GetFoo()` (the client code does not reference assembly B), the compiler will gives an error, because `IBar` "is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly B". Note that my code only needs to know about Foo, and it contains no reference to the interface.

Is it possible to not have to reference B? As far as I know there is no need for the runtime to know about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That scenario works in native languages like C++ with COM because the interface simply specifies a convention that is checked at compile time but not enforced at runtime. However, in .NET the CLR enforces type safety at runtime and so it needs to reference the assembly in which the interface is defined.

If your situation allows it, you may want to break out the interface into a separate "contracts" assembly and have both assemblies reference it. It will be a very small assembly and should load very quickly.

Comment: just curious, that's your actual family name?

Comment: Indeed. I've recently come to the realization that many people assume I am being a smartass, but it's my name.

Comment: +1 for contracts assembly. We do this in all our apps for interfaces and value objects. It's a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces are needed at runtime and assembly B is needed.

If the caller actually doesn't care about the interface, you can choose not to implement it and then don't need assembly b.  If you sometimes need it and sometimes don't, you can use `#if` directives and compiler flags to create two versions of assembly a, one that uses b and one that doesn't.  It's way overkill IMO though to have two versions.

Answer (score 1):

no, if you are dealing with classes that implement certain interfaces, all those interfaces should be available to the places where you create or retrieve the classes.

usually this is solved the other way round, you work against interfaces and not concrete classes then you only add the reference to the interface assembly and not to the classes.